# Using relationships in Laravel Eloquent with bridge table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-4.2

I have an app that handles user info, and one of the pieces of data we collect is what school(s) they're attending.  We have a `User` object, `School` object, and a `UserSchool` object.

This is the user_schools table:

`user_id (int),school_id (int)`

With the following records for instance:

```
100, 20
200, 500
200, 10
300, 10
```

I'm trying to get all schools for the current user (say user 200).  This is my UserSchool object:

```
class UserSchool extends Model
{
    var $table = 'user_schools';

    function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    function school() {
        return$this->belongsTo('School');
    }

}
```

In `User` I have the following relations defined:

```
public function schools()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('School', 'UserSchool');
    }

    public function userSchools()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('UserSchool');
    }
```

When I `var_dump($user->schools)` I get no results, even though I know it should be returning multiple `School`s.  What am I doing wrong? I'm sure this must have been asked before but I don't know what the actual term for this intermediate type of relationship is (bridge table? pivot table?).

Edit:  Either way, most of the examples I've looked at haven't worked.  I've also tried:

```
public function schools()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('School', 'UserSchool',  'school_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact you don't need to have `UserSchool` object here for this relationship

For `User` model you can use create the following relationship:

```
public function schools() 
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(School::class, 'user_schools');
}
```

And now you can get schools of user using something like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);
foreach ($user->schools as $school) 
{
   echo $school->name;
}
```

This is standard [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many)

Comment: Worked fine, however for PHP 5.4 had to change School::class to "School".   Thank you. I would have thought a hasManyThrough relationship would have been required, so thanks for pointing me in the right way.